# Trigger event on uploading file to Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Is there a way to monitor a Google Drive folder to trigger an Apps Script (or otherwise in GCP) when a new file is uploaded to that folder?

Comment: Hey there @Hasam! It is possible to track a Drive folder in a timely (clock-driven) way. Would that be an appropriate solution to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google drive api supports [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) you could set up your server to listen for changes in the directory.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https ://mydomain.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

The question is weather or not the notification will pick up that a new file was uploaded or if its just going to notify you for something like a name change on the directory.

check [notification-events](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#understanding-drive-api-notification-events)

Comment: I would love to hear back if it does notify you for items created in directories.  #justcurious

Comment: I am doing some work on it now. It does notify you when you uplaod a new file to the folder. It does not tell you which file has been uploaded. Instead I am working on using the trigger to get a list of files in the folder, then remembering the list and next time I get a trigger comparing the list.